# Xcp-Ng VMs hardware spec recommendations

Tags: windows, hardware

I'm upgrading host machine in order to host 20VMs on xcp-ng
Each VMs is windows server 2019, 200GB had, 32GB.

What is the best server in market and the right spec for it?

Or noob question. Is xcp-ng good enough for long run project?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcp-ng is more than sufficient for a long project.

I would look at EPYC based systems, you can find some good spec servers through HP, Dell, etc or build your own.

Comment: Agreed, EPYC based systems can work for the OP. Something like Proxmox or Starwinds virtual appliances can easily virtualize these systems.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft recommending one vCPU per Windows Server VM and a typical 1:4(6) vCPU:core ratio (Sizing guide link attached), any dual socket server should work. We’re Dell shop, so R7xx line is brilliant for these types of the tasks. You can absolutely go single socket AMD, but it’s more about memory bandwidth and PCIe lanes.

Xen-based XCP-NG is solid, but it’s KVM winning people’s minds as of now. If you plan some long run you’d better invest into KVM learning curve. IMHO.

P.S. VM sizing guide I mentioned is here:

https://www.networkcomputing.com/cloud-infrastructure/virtual-machine-sizing-3-mistakes-avoid#

Good one around VDI is available from Microsoft directly, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/virtual-machine-recs